# Change article title and read more button style for particular articles in Joomla3.x

Tags: joomla3.2

I am using Joomla3.2 for my site development. I wish to reduce the size of the article's title in particular pages without affecting other pages.

By default it will take `<h1>` and I want to reduce this into `<h4>`.

I would also like to reduce the size of the read more button size in the article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the usage of `<h1>` for the article's title vs `<h4>` is not a matter of size alone; but most importantly it tells search engines what the page is about.

What you want is simply to apply a different style to the `<h1>` in some particular pages.

In order to achieve this you might

1. add a css suffix to the specific menu items that are linked to
   the articles whose title is too large;
2. add the Itemid parameter in the `<body>` tag in your template

Whichever you choose, in the end you'll have a means of discriminating the articles - be it the page class or the Itemid - which you will use in your css to apply a smaller font-size.

So for example your selectors may be:

```
body.item-113 h1, body.item-116 h1
```

or

```
.someCustomClassYouAddedToTheMenuItem h1
```